# R: How to compute the mean by ID in a given data frame?

Tags: r, apply

I have the following data:

```
ID       Value
1         3
1         5
```

How can I compute the mean by ID, and put the mean in the data frame as a new variable such that it is repeated for the same ID. The result should look like this:

```
ID       Value   Mean
1         3       4
1         5       4
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try `df$mean <- ave(df$Value, df$ID, FUN = mean)`

Comment: `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(ID)%>% mutate(Mean=mean(Value))`

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked. I was initially using tapply but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the mean by group using `ave()`. Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you can do the following:

```
df$Mean <- with(df, ave(Value, ID, FUN=mean))
```

This adds `Mean` as another column in your data frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'ave' function from 'base' R:

```
df=data.frame(ID=c(1,1), value=c(3,5))
df['mean'] <- ave(df$value, df$ID, FUN=mean)

> df
###   ID value mean
### 1  1     3    4
### 2  1     5    4
```